# Scala Enumeration ValueSet.isEmpty slow

Tags: java, scala, enumeration, scala-collections, bitset

I am using Scala Enumeration ValueSets in a fairly high-throughput setting - creating, testing, union'ing and intersecting about 10M sets/second/core.  I didn't expect this to be a big deal, because I had read somewhere that they were backed by BitSets, but surprisingly ValueSet.isEmpty showed up as a hot spot in a profiling session with YourKit.

To verify, I decided to try and reimplement what I needed using the Java BitSet, while trying to retain some of the type-safety of using Scala Enumerations.  (code review moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74795/scala-bitset-implemented-with-java-bitset-for-use-in-scala-enumerations-to-repl )  The good news is, changing just my ValueSets to these BitSets did indeed lop off 25% of my run-time, so I don't know what ValueSet is really doing under the hood but it could be improved...

EDIT: Reviewing the ValueSet source seems to indicate that isEmpty is definitely O(N), implemented using the general SetLike.isEmpty.  **Considering ValueSet is implemented with a BitSet, is this a bug?**

EDIT: This was the backtrace from the profiler.  This seems like a crazy way to implement isEmpty on a bitset.

[image: Backtrace of hot spot in YourKit]

Comment: "I don't know what ValueSet is really doing under the hood ". The source is available, if you wanted to take a look: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L1

Comment: It sounds like you have working code that you want feedback on. If that's the case, you should move your question to [codereview.se]. Otherwise, please pare down your question and make the actual question more evident - it took me a while to even find what you were asking about.

Comment: Thanks, looking now.  So far, it seems to confirm what I found in the profiler (attached); the ValueSet.isEmpty, at least, is implemented entirely with generic algorithms, neglecting that for a BitSet, it should be no more difficult than (x == 0).

Comment: Chris- I will split it into two as you suggest, one to code review my replacement, and one to discuss why ValueSet.isEmpty is O(N) when it's implemented with a BitSet, which honestly looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I'm all for looking under the hood, but this design asks too much of any mortal coder.

The immortals, of course, have infinite time at their disposal.

`Enumeration.ValueSet` is backed by a `BitSet` but is not one itself. Something about favoring composition.

[Did you hear about the heir to a fortune who gave it all up to pursue his love of music? He favored composition over inheritance. Did I just make that up or did I hear it at Java One?]

No doubt, ValueSet should delegate more methods to the BitSet, including isEmpty.

I was going to suggest trying `values.iterator.isEmpty`, but that just tests `hasNext` which loops through all possible values checking for contains.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/BitSetLike.scala#L109

If I'm reading that correctly.

The best option is `e.values.toBitMask forall (_ == 0)`, which is the moral equivalent of `BitSet.isEmpty`.